# PHP post Data is empty for large files had set all required ini values still not working

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to upload a 12 GB file through file upload but the post data is empty

It work for 8GB file but failing for larger than that

My php.ini values are

```
max_execution_time 30000000000
max_input_time 60000000000
memory_limit 6G
post_max_size 800G
upload_max_filesize 200G
```

Please Help! thanks in advance

Comment: What errors did you get when you checked your error log?

Comment: There is no error for apache error log file i checked that but no luck.

Comment: What errors did you get when you checked your ***PHP error log***? Where's the code you used that led you to the conclusion that "*post Data is empty*"?

Comment: There is a limit for post uri string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: There was no error at the end of post 
if ( !empty($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) && empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) )
  echo 'The uploaded zip was too large. You must upload a file smaller than ' . ini_get("upload_max_filesize");
i had checked by this code that the post is empty

Comment: Try increasing `memory_limit` to larger than the max file size i.e. `memory_limit 13G`

Comment: @RiggsFolly OK I changed it trying upload now hold!

New values are

memory_limit 20G
post_max_size 18G
upload_max_filesize 16G

Comment: Its still not working does anyone know why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

> If the upload_max_filesize is larger than post_max_size, you must increase post_max_size so that it is bigger than upload_max_size.
>
> If the value of post_max_size is larger than memory_limit, you must increase > memory_limit so that it is larger than post_max_size.

Therefore try to increase `memory_limit` or decrease `post_max_size`.

[This article explains in details](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404784/how-do-i-increase-the-php-upload-limits)

**EDIT**

I've encountered a similar problem today: when I attempt to upload large files, no response returns. Error log showed the following:

> [Wed Nov 02 07:45:28.428652 2016] [fcgid:warn] [pid 15602] [client
>   213.24.127.118:22388] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 139264 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072), referer: https://domain.com/path

Such problem is solved by setting `FcgidMaxRequestLen` in `vhosts` file to whatever value is fine for you.

Comment: So this means that if i want to upload a 12GB file than my memory limit should be arround 20GB and post max size should be arrounf 18 GB ?

Comment: OK I changed it trying upload now hold! New values are memory_limit 20G post_max_size 18G upload_max_filesize 16G

Comment: Were you successful with this?  I'm finding a long delay after the upload has reached 100% (a few minutes) before the file becomes available as completed..

Answer (score 0):

set **max_execution_time** to (0) zero. Zero means the script can run forever.
Next set **max_input_time** to (-1). This specified that -1 is unlimited because no script can be executed with a negative time.

Example

```
max_execution_time = 0
max_input_time = -1
```

You must set the value of **memory_limit** larger than **post_max_size** and
**upload_max_filesize**. In your case, set the value like bellow.

```
memory_limit = 20G
post_max_size = 15G
upload_max_filesize = 15G
```

Then of course restart apache server or restart all services